# SQL Joins Performance Considerations

Tags: mysql

I am looking for better way to achieve Result 2 that I have achieved using Query 2. In simple words, I am trying to merge File and CD columns into a single row for each SalesDetailId. It's obvious that Query 2 is not ideal for performance. Query 1 and Result 1 is what I started with which shows the kind of data structure I am working with.

### Query 1:

```
SELECT 
  SDT.SalesDetailId,
  RlFile.Code AS FILE,
  RlCD.Code AS CD
FROM SalesDetail SDT
INNER JOIN Sales S
  ON S.SalesID = SDT.SalesID
LEFT JOIN SalesReflookup SRL 
    ON SRL.SalesID = S.SalesID AND SRL.RefLookupTypeId IN (30,200)  
LEFT JOIN reflookup.reflookup RlFileStatus 
    ON RlFileStatus.reflookupid = SRL.reflookupid AND RlFile.reflookuptypeid = 30
LEFT JOIN reflookup.reflookup RlCatastrophe 
    ON RlCD.reflookupid = SRL.reflookupid AND RlCatastrophe.reflookuptypeid = 200
WHERE 
    SDT.SalesDetailId = 4042910
```

### Result 1:

```
| SalesDetailId | FILE |  CD  |
|       4042910 | C    | NULL |
|       4042910 | NULL | 95E  |
```

### Query 2:

```
SELECT 
  SDT.SalesDetailId,
  FILE.Code AS FILE,
  CD.Code AS CD
FROM SalesDetail SDT
INNER JOIN Sales S
  ON S.SalesID = SDT.SalesID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
          RL.code,SRL.SalesID
          FROM reflookup.reflookup RL
          INNER JOIN SalesReflookup SRL 
            ON RL.reflookupid = SRL.reflookupid AND RL.reflookuptypeid = 30) FILE ON FILE.SalesID = S.SalesID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
          RL.code,SRL.SalesID
          FROM reflookup.reflookup RL
          INNER JOIN SalesReflookup SRL 
            ON RL.reflookupid = SRL.reflookupid AND RL.reflookuptypeid = 200) CD ON CD.SalesID = S.SalesID

WHERE SDT.SalesDetailId = 4042910
```

### Result 2 (Desired Result)

```
| SalesDetailId | FILE | CD |
|       4042910 | C           | 95E            |
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server  ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` on the first query:

```
SELECT SDT.SalesDetailId,
       MAX(RlFile.Code) AS FILE,
       MAX(RlCD.Code) AS CD
FROM . . .
WHERE  SDT.SalesDetailId = 4042910
GROPU BY SDT.SalesDetailId;
```